# Estimate the size of a new mail

Tags: java, email, jakarta-mail

We have a postfix server configured with `message_size_limit=10240000` (the default) and I would now like to prevent the creation of any mail that is bigger than that. Because I get otherwise a "connection broken" error, which is difficult to present to the user in a meaningful error message.

The definition of `message_size_limit` is:

> The maximal size in bytes of a message, including envelope
>   information.

My question is: How can I calculate / predict / estimate the size in bytes of a created mail with lots of different attachments? `javax.mail.Message.size()` is only available when receiving a mail.

Comment: Add up the size of the attachments?

Comment: I'm looking for the _raw bytes_ (changed the question to reflect that), so the size of the attachments will need to be much smaller than the configured 10 MB.

Comment: I don't understand. Once you have the text and attachments you can estimate the size of the email.

Comment: My question was not _if_ I can estimate the size of the email, but _how_ I can do it. And for that I can't just sum the size of the attachments and texts, because the size of the mail in bytes is much bigger than that due to the different encodings.

Comment: ... It's base64, and generally 2-4 bytes per character max for text. Obviously building the message and writing it as suggested will be pretty precise, but estimating it still doesn't seem that tricky. When you tried what I'm suggesting how far off was it? I'd be a little surprised if it wasn't close enough to be useful.

Comment: I have to admit, that I did something similar first. But while working on it I noticed that it is _not_ as simple as this: BASE64 encoded strings are usually split with newlines, which may even occur at different positions (e.g. 64 or 72 characters per line) depending on the implementation. And quoted-printable characters are neither 2, nor 4, nor 2-4 bytes but either 1 byte (for ASCII characters) or a multiple of 3 bytes (for the UTF-8 encoding in quoted-printable). As you see, the solution of Bill down below is much easier and less error prone and will not add much performance overhead.

Comment: Fair enough--although newlines in a base64 string aren't going to break your estimate that much (it's an estimate); the representation of printable characters will depend on your data, encoding, etc. but it sounds like you have a limited set of input data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take your draft Message object and use `Message.writeTo` to write it to a stream that does nothing with the data but just counts the number of bytes written:

```
public long getMessageSize(Message message) {
    CountingOutputStream counter = new CountingOutputStream(new NullOutputStream());
    message.saveChanges();
    message.writeTo(counter);
    return counter.getByteCount();
}
```

The `CountingOutputStream` is from *commons-io*, but the one from *Guava* or a slower `ByteArrayOutputStream` will do as well.

That will give you an estimate on the overall size of the message.

Doing this is going to be expensive so you can't (for example) do it for every character typed into the message by the user.  You need to do it only on certain events (e.g., adding an attachment) or after (e.g.) 5 minutes of typing data into a message.  You need a strategy to reduce the cost of the operation while providing timely feedback to the user.

If you do this, be sure to call `Message.saveChanges` before each call to `Message.writeTo`, and before really sending the message.

Comment: Thank you for the reference to `saveChanges`, I added an example to have a "One-Stop-Shop" solution.

Comment: Since Java 11 you can use the JDK alternative: `OutputStream.nullOutputStream()`.
Also, don't forget to close the stream!

Answer (score 1):

One thing which some don't realize is that binary attachments are always `base64` encoded, and occasionally, even ASCII attachments.  Any attachment of `K` bytes will ultimately be `33%` larger due to the encoding process.  So you need to know if the folks that configure the server take that into consideration.

Otherwise, what appears to be an email less than the advertised maximum, can be substantially more.

Comment: This is not really an answer to my question. I know, that I can calculate the BASE64 encoded size (and add the newlines, which many often forget) - but there is so much more like the size of the text messages, which are often in `quoted-printable`. I added the definition of `message_size_limit` to my question to indicate, that I know that we are looking for the raw number of bytes.

Comment: Since you said you wanted to calculate sizes I figured that would be useful information to know for the calculation.

Comment: Thanks for your effort. If you add _all_ the information that is necessary to calculate the size, I would accept it right away as correct answer. But as it is now it is more a comment than an answer.

Comment: Having implemented both protocols and message formats I know they can be very dynamic.  If I had to do this I would simply calculate what I know about such as attachments and the message body and add some percentage for overhead.  It is not a 100% solution because some messages may get rejected that normally wouldn't and others would not get rejected at the client but will at the server.